# Does Google use Gmail to discover new links?

Tags: gmail, google-search

I've just read an article ([source](http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Vorsicht-beim-Skypen-Microsoft-liest-mit-1857620.html) - it's German, I'm sorry) which reports that Microsoft uses Skype to discover new websites (probably for Bing).

I know that Google makes use of Gmail to generate personalized advertising. Does Google also use Gmail to discover new (deep web) websites?

Comment: That's how the ads in your inbox always seem related to your emails

Comment: Related: [Does google read my email?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23407/does-google-read-my-email)

Comment: You might find this 2011 Gawker article of interest since it discusses some 'data trolling' accusations in re. Gmail http://gawker.com/5800868/how-google-spies-on-your-gmail-account-and-how-to-stop-it

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any discussion of URL collection in [Google's Privacy Policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/). They only mention location, devices, logs, information you share publicly, etc.

Google already gets a ton of signals for URLs to index. Google+, for instance, is a goldmine of URLs.

I seriously doubt that Google is trawling your Gmail messages for links.